# flutter_inappwebview and stripe.js blank screen

Tags: flutter, laravel-cashier, laravel-9, flutter-inappwebview

When loading a webpage that has the stripe javascript on it the InAppWebView is just a blank page, onLoadStop reports the URI: [https://m.stripe.network/inner.html?url=\*\*&title=\*\*&referrer=\*\*&muid=NA&sid=NA&version=6&preview=false](https://m.stripe.network/inner.html?url=%5C*%5C*&title=%5C*%5C*&referrer=%5C*%5C*&muid=NA&sid=NA&version=6&preview=false)

The flutter app is a simple InAppWebView that mirrors a laravel website using the cashier/stripe subscription combination. The page works in a browser and when launched using url_launcher, but this requires the user to re-login and navigate back to where they were.

Is there any way to allow this page to load in flutter_inappwebview? Or, create the card-element element without the JavaScript include (https://js.stripe.com/v3)?

JavaScript code:

```js
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script> -- this is the culprit
<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}');
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        hidePostalCode: true,
        style: style
    });
    card.mount('#card-element');
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
    });
    const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
    const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        console.log("attempting");
        const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
            clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                }
        });
        if (error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = error.message;
        } else {
            paymentMethodHandler(setupIntent.payment_method);
        }
    });
    function paymentMethodHandler(payment_method) {
        var form = document.getElementById('subscribe-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'payment_method');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', payment_method);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Stripe doesn't like custom headers, so if you add a header to the request it will block it.